# Eclipse Gradle Import with AspectJ Configuration

Tags: eclipse, gradle, aspectj

I have a Gradle project which leverages AOP (from Spring 3.x.x) which I have imported into Eclipse (STS). When I use the Gradle's context menu to refresh dependencies/rebuild source I then have to convert to a AspectJ project in able for me to run my tests correctly (the AspectJ Runtime library isn't on the build path to fulfill the factory-method in the bean definition). I don't have the spring-aspects.jar located anywhere and this deploys to Tomcat without issue (again no aspectJ in the libs/ folder).

```
<bean id="fooBarAspect" class="foo.Bar"   factory-method="aspectOf"  >
```

This process works but is painful as it makes me rebuild twice anytime I need to refresh dependencies and run integration tests.

```
dependencies {

ajc 'org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.7.3'
aspects 'org.springframework:spring-aspects:3.2.4.RELEASE'

compile (
        'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.7.3'
        )
```

}

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

For AspectJ:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

ext.aspectjVersion = '1.7.4'

configurations {

    ajc
    aspects
    aspectCompile
    ajInpath

    compile {
        extendsFrom aspects
    }

}

compileJava {
  sourceCompatibility="1.7"
  targetCompatibility="1.7"

  doLast{
      ant.taskdef( resource:"org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties", classpath: configurations.ajc.asPath)
      ant.iajc(
          source:sourceCompatibility, 
          target:targetCompatibility, 
          destDir:sourceSets.main.output.classesDir.absolutePath, 
          maxmem:   "512m", 
          fork:     "true",
          inpath:   configurations.ajInpath.asPath,
          aspectPath:configurations.aspects.asPath,  
          sourceRootCopyFilter:"**/.svn/*,**/*.java",
          classpath:"${configurations.compile.asPath};${configurations.aspectCompile.asPath}"){
          sourceroots{
              sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each{
                  pathelement(location:it.absolutePath)
              }
          }
      }
  }
}


dependencies {
      ajc             "org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.7.3"
      compile         "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.7.3"
      aspects       group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aspects', version: springVersion 
      aspectCompile group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.0-api', version: '1.0.0.Final'
      aspectCompile   group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-tx', version: springVersion 
      aspectCompile   group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: springVersion 
}
```

For Eclipse we have to do bit a manual code:

```
eclipseClasspath {
        withXml { xmlProvider ->
          def classpath = xmlProvider.asNode()
          def parser = new XmlParser()

          classpath.classpathentry.findAll{ entry ->
              entry.@kind == 'var' && configurations.runtime.find {entry.@path.endsWith(it.name) && !entry.@path.contains('servlet-api')
              }.each { entry ->
              def attrs = entry.attributes ?: parser.createNode(entry, 'attributes', [:])
              parser.createNode(attrs, 'attribute', [name: 'org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency', value: '../'])
          }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is imo, that the project in eclipse must be marked as aspectj project in order to use the ajc compiler instead of the "normal" compiler. How did you declare the aspectj compilation in your build.gradle file? just adding the aspectj-rt to the compile classpath is definitely not enough.

You can manipulate the eclipse project configuration on xml level using gradle. I did this a long time ago using the withXml hook. have a look at the build.gradle file at

https://github.com/breskeby/gradleplugins/blob/0.9-upgrade/aspectjPlugin/aspectJ.gradle#L29

The way the aspectj eclipse plugin works might be outdated and you probably update it to fit your needs, but you should get the idea.